# Keep only alphabetic characters (multilingual) in a string

Tags: python, string, multilingual

On stackoverflow there are a lot of answers about how to keep only alphabetic characters from a string, the most common accepted is the famous regex `'[^a-zA-Z]'`. But this answer is totally wrong because it supposes everybody only write English... I thought I could down vote all these answers but I finally thought it would be more constructive to ask the question again, because I can't find the answer.

Is there an easy (or not...) way in python to keep only alphabetic characters from a string that works for all languages ? I think maybe about a library that could do like [xregexp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) in javascript... By all languages I mean english but also french, russian, chinese, greec...etc

Comment: I think it may be easier to include the whole unicode and exclude non-alphabetic characters

Comment: @MoonCheesez I was thinking of exactly the same way. There's an easy way of doing this in shell scripting but I can't think of a Pythonic way right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [^\W\d_]

With Python3 or the `re.UNICODE` flag in Python2, you could use `[^\W\d_]`.

> \W : If UNICODE is set, this will match anything other than [0-9_] plus
>   characters classified as not alphanumeric in the Unicode character
>   properties database.

So `[^\W\d_]` is anything which is not not alphanumeric or not a digit or not an underscore. In other words, it's any alphabetic character. :)

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("[^\W\d_]", "jüste Ä tösté 1234 ßÜ א д", re.UNICODE)
['j', 'ü', 's', 't', 'e', 'Ä', 't', 'ö', 's', 't', 'é', 'ß', 'Ü', 'א', 'д']
```

## Remove digits first, then look for "\w"

To avoid this convoluted logic, you could also remove digits and underscores first, and then look for alphanumeric characters :

```
>>> without_digit = re.sub("[\d_]", "", "jüste Ä tösté 1234 ßÜ א д", re.UNICODE) 
>>> re.findall("\w", without_digit, re.UNICODE)
['j', 'ü', 's', 't', 'e', 'Ä', 't', 'ö', 's', 't', 'é', 'ß', 'Ü', 'א', 'д']
```

## regex module

It seems that [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module could help, since it understands `\p{L}` or `[\w--\d_]`.

> This regex implementation is backwards-compatible with the standard
>   ‘re’ module, but offers additional functionality.

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> re.findall("\p{L}", "jüste Ä tösté 1234 ßÜ א д", re.UNICODE)
['j', 'ü', 's', 't', 'e', 'Ä', 't', 'ö', 's', 't', 'é', 'ß', 'Ü', 'א', 'д']
```

(Tested with Anaconda Python 3.6)

Comment: I tried the `regex` module and `\p{L}`, it looks like it keeps only latin letters with no accents... Maybe I missed something somewhere but it should works regarding one of the documentation example :  `[\p{L}--QW] # Set containing all letters except ‘Q’ and ‘W’`

Comment: it looks like your first and second example works perfectly :)

Comment: I use version 2.7.9. Tried with version 3 but I have an issue trying to import `regex` installed with pip and since i'm not a python expert and didn't want to spend to much time trying to import `regex` I used 2.7.9 for tests.

Comment: i mark as answer but have some doubts for the regex module solution since for what i tried it only kept letters with no accents (tested with python 2.7.9)

Comment: Just kind of new with python so take me time to test all this.
Tried with this code and the output is only latin letters

`# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-`
`re.UNICODE`
`print (re.findall("[\p{L}]","jüste Ä tösté 1234 ßÜ א д"))`

Comment: Looks like i'm close, this is my output `['j', '\xc3', 's', 't', 'e', '\xc3', 't', '\xc3', 's', 't', '\xc3', '\xc3', '\xc3', '\xd0']`. It's not a console problem since I can't print any language in it. Now I just have to find a way to replace theses "\x" values. I 'm just realizing that encoding is not the easiest things to deal with python :)

Comment: ok many thanks for your help @Eric, it was very helpful ;) I don't want to bother you anymore since you answered correctly to my question. I think I can go to the end by myself from now since my current problem is not related to my question. It's more encoding problem than get rid of characters in a string now.... thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Laurent: My pleasure, I also learn a lot while answering Python and Ruby questions.